# Is the Stargate storyline continued after Stargate: Universe?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

The *Stargate* storyline begins in the [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111282/), and then continues in [Stargate: SG1](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118480/), then [Stargate: Atlantis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0374455/), and finally in [Stargate: Universe](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1286039/).

Are there any films, novels, or TV series that take place in this universe after *Stargate: Universe*?  If there are none presently, are there any announcements of works in development?

(For example, the *Stargate: SG1* series was extended through two films, [Continuum](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0929629/) and [The Ark of Truth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0942903/), and both *SG1* and *Atlantis* have several tie-in novels).

Comment: I've edited to try and keep this asking the same thing (and keep the existing answer appropriate), but make this more timeless (so that people coming to this page in the future still find it relevant).  Please feel free to revert, although my hope is that this edit makes the question more likely to be re-opened.

Comment: On a side note i'm very emotionally disturbed that stargate universe has ended. I've never loved a series as much as it.

Comment: After universe is's pretty much an over with series and storyline. I think it went for quite a LONG time and did so quite well...

Comment: If you're desperate for more Stargate, [Big Finish](http://bigfinish.com/Stargate-SG-1-and-Atlantis) has done some audio play productions. They're within the existing SG-1/Atlantis timeline rather than after them. I don't believe they're canon but they are done with the original actors. It's also not a film, novel, or TV series.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As per [Joseph Mallozzi](http://josephmallozzi.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/may-5-2011-doggies-eating-peanut-butter/) (an Executive Producer on SG-1, SG:A and SGU) in one of his regular "Mail Bag" blog posts:

> Fancy Trav writes: “Obviously Stargate
>   Universe is over after 2 seasons. Is
>   that a definate that it is over
>   forever? Has a good run and support so
>   may be able to get it back on? Another
>   network “may” pick it up? Or am I
>   hoping too much and its over for
>   good??”
>
> Answer: Again, **sorry to be the bearer
>   of bad news but it is over for SG-1,
>   Atlantis, and Universe.**

*(My emphasis)*

Comment: That seems to leave open the possibility for Stargate-X. So it only tells you the series we've already seen have run their course.

Comment: I want to downvote :'(

Comment: Given what happened to Universe, I wouldn't trust the producers with another SG installment. They seem to have lost respect for the fans that made them successful in the first place.

Comment: @Paperjam, see that's where we'd have to agree to disagree as I thought Universe was fantastic and loved watching it just as much as I did SG1 and SGA. I'd suggest reading Joseph Mallozzi's blog (seriously, go there, read it, it's well worth it - he's done a series of "reminiscing about Series X of SG-1" posts that are great!) and you'll see just how much time/respect he has shown for the franchises fans! =) What happened to Universe was unfortunate, but SGA and SG1 would have probably gone the same way.... (cont/d)

Comment: Compare the viewing figures for SGA Series 5 episode 6 of 1.6mil (US) viewers which wikipedia states is "considered average for the season" as compared to 1.9mil viewers for Series 1 episode 6 of SGU (the figures from wikipedia's SGU S1 page give an average of 1.7m US viewers per episode - higher than that of SGA's final season),... The reasons for SGU's failure, whatever they are, aren't because of the reason you suggest. (Personally, I blame SyFy for poor scheduling.)

Comment: Personally, I think SG:U gave fans more credit for being able to follow a literate character driven storyline than they deserved, considering that so many just stopped watching and were angry because it didn't have enough testosterone driven action sequences.

Comment: This answer speaks to TV series, but not films or novels.

Answer (score 14):

## Yes, there is the *Stargate Universe: Back to Destiny* comic series

From June 2017 to September 2018, American Mythology Productions produced a six-issue comic series entitled *[Stargate Universe: Back to Destiny](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Stargate_Universe:_Back_to_Destiny)*. It is a canon continuation set after the Season 2 finale of the TV show.

Here is the publisher's summary of the first issue:

> *Stargate Universe* the comic book begins right where Season Two of the acclaimed science fiction TV series ended, with the crew and unwilling passengers of Destiny set to cross a vast expanse of space with no margin for error. With almost all of the crew of the ancient starship *Destiny* in suspended animation, only Eli Wallace is left awake to repair his own stasis pod before time runs out. While he races against time, a new and unexpected danger threatens the fragile plan designed to keep everyone alive and away from the aliens who had been pursuing them. What strange new menace confronts Eli, Colonel Young, Doctor Rush and the others? You’ll have to pick up this issue to find out!

Comment: How can't this answer be accepted as it perfectly answer the question ?

Comment: @TinyDoowy The profile of the OP says “Last seen Sep 8 '17”, and only they can accept an answer.

Comment: Hello darkness my olf friend :'(

Answer (score 8):

While the extant 3 series may be done for on the small screen...

It's highly likely that there will be semi-canonical novels; there have been for the other series. They usually get announced once the manuscript is sent for layout.

Likewise, it's possible there will be comics.

It's quite possible that a further SG derivative may be done later.

Whether they're set after SGU is yet to be seen, but it's highly likely, as that means far less canon to avoid.

But none of these are announced yet that I've heard of. Wait and see...

Answer (score 3):

There was talk of a direct-to-DVD Atlantis movie and it was in the IMDB, but it's no longer listed.

Comment: See Rob's answer.  It was canned.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed at least one short-lived franchise which takes place after SGU: [Stargate Infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Infinity) is set in the future.

That said, it's not actually considered canon. Sadly, I've never seen it myself, so I can't comment on its quality.

Comment: The quality is, from what I've seen, sub-par compared to SG-1.  Comes from the translation to a children's cartoon, the reduced budget, and the lack of close ties to the real world.

Comment: Stargate Infinity was created long before SG-1 finished, and worked off of the assumption that the Goa'uld were never defeated.  At best you have to consider it an alternate timeline.

Answer (score 2):

The show's producer Joseph Malozzi has confirmed that there are no plans to further the series. In addition to confirming the death of the SG:U TV series (with the [striking of the sets](http://www.gatefans.net/there-will-be-no-stargate-universe-movie-the-sets-will-be-struck/) and the dismissal of the staff) he's also revealed his [tentative plotlines](https://josephmallozzi.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/may-12-2011-stargate-universe-beyond-season-2-what-might-have-been/) for the third season.

The sole author of an SG:U novelisation; J.M.Swallow confirmed in [this blog post](http://forum.gateworld.net/threads/86391-Why-no-novels/page2) that despite his desire (and presumably his request) to write further books within the same universe, he was unable to do so due to internal rights wranglings at MGM post their bankruptcy in 2010:

> **KEK:** *I'm guessing it's because the first one sold really poorly. It's a stupid indicator really though, as it was only a novelization
>   of the pilot. Hardly indicative of the sort of number they could
>   expect if they made a genuine canon continuation in novel form.*
>
> **JMSwallows :** *Actually, as I understand it, the Air novelization sold fairly well...*
>
> **KEK :** *How do you know that?*
>
> **JMSwallows :** ***Because I wrote it.***

On the upside, there will be more Stargate films [in the near future.](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Stargate-Reboot-Based-Original-Trilogy-Plans-Franchise-43679.html) so there will almost certainly be additional novelisations to read.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing concrete for what happened after the end of SGU. There were several plans on the part of the show's producers, writers, and staff as to how to continue it, though.

The one they seem to have been going for was that three years later, everyone would come to and find Eli half-crazy and living in the shuttle.

Once the series ended, and they were trying to make a straight-to-DVD movie, the plan seemed to be "The gate from the Milky Way is open, and tons of people and supplies from the SGC pour through, including some characters we know." That, too, was set "Three years later."

When the season 3 and movie options had expired, one of the producers simply said, "They'll wake up in a hundred years."

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that the director of the original movie that sold the rights to mgm, has said that sg-1, atlantis, and universe are NOT considered canon in his opinion to the original movie. Which gives cause for the possible movie trilogy reboot I've been reading about that would actually be canon.

Comment: Great, but can you provide a reference, or even the actual quote itself? Nothing personal, but we prefer not to take people's word for it here

Comment: Granted his word has merit concerning the theatrical release (despite the fact he sold the rights) but by his own reasoning he can't proclaim what is or isn't canon with the TV shows. Not that he ever tried to but just to point out if there is no overlap then there can be no conflict even if both continuities were to be developed further.

Answer (score 0):

MGM has released 10 short episodes called [Stargate:Origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Origins) earlier this year.

It was announced on July 20, 2017 at the 2017 San Diego Comic Con as part of Stargate SG-1's 20th anniversary celebration. The series consists of 10 episodes, each 10 minutes in length, essentially a 10-episode feature length movie, and expands upon the existing mythology of the Stargate franchise.

Stargate Origins premiered with 3 episodes on February 14, 2018 on MGM's Stargate Command subscription service. A 104 minutes long ‘Feature Cut‘ titled Stargate Origins: Catherine was released on June 19, 2018 on digital retail outlets around the world in SD, HD, and 4K formats.

‘Feature Cut‘ additions include a fresh sound mix, enhanced visual effects, a new title sequence, and subtitles in 12 different languages.

Comment: None of these take place after SGU though...

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of "new" **canon** stories set after the end of SGU on television.

First there's the Back to Destiny comic series but also a Back to Pegasus series focused mainly on SGA that also involve the SGC. (I'll warn you that these SGA issues have numerous errors ranging from spelling to continuity and the characters don't look much like themselves but often too much like each other, though I think any fan will still enjoy them.)

There are also several paperback novels that continue the SGA arc but annoyingly these are **a totally separate and incompatible canon continuity as the comics**.