# Stargate media post-Universe

Tags: stargate

It's now been almost four years since *Stargate Universe* flopped, and as far as I'm aware there's been no word of anything else in that universe since then. I can understand this being the case with the TV series'; but I'm wondering if there are other media, especially novels. I can think of several things that are begging for it such as *Universe*'s continuation and the Stargate going public. Does anyone know if there's any new novels set after *Universe*, or any other plans in place?

I'm aware that [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3461/is-the-stargate-storyline-continued-after-stargate-universe) basically asks the same, but since it was answered shortly after that happened the question was still somewhat up in the air. I'm hoping things have changed since then.

Comment: Reportedly Emmerich and Devlin (the guys behind the original *Stargate* movie) are going to helm a new movie trilogy. Details are sparse though, so it's not clear if they're going to be set after *Universe*, or even acknowledge the TV shows at all

Comment: Just found this: "In May 2014, MGM announced a re-imagined version of the original 1994 film to be produced as a trilogy with Warner Bros. Pictures. Emmerich will direct and Devlin will produce. This set, of 2 sequel films to the original Stargate Starring Kurt Russell and James Spader, will take a dramatically different course than the SG-1 and Atlantis universe created in the following 15 years."

I wouldn't link to Wikipedia except that the reference link is broken. I'm sorry, but if it's not referencing the 15-odd years of Stargate TV I'm not interested.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's a mistake on MGM's part. Well, we'll see.

Comment: As you've already pointed out, this question is a dupe of the earlier question. If you're unsatisfied with the answers, the correct procedure is to a) Ask questions via comment (or) b) Research your own answer (or) c) Raise a bounty on the question with a bespoke note saying that you're looking for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I've linked to a couple of articles below (one actually references the other, but offers a little more speculation) because it seems as if the original MGM press release is no longer available through their website. Plans have been announced to create a new *Stargate* trilogy, but the wording and what we know about the original creators of *Stargate* suggests that it will largely ignore the continuity and mythology established by *SG-1, Atlantis, and Universe.*

My searching isn't finding me a source, but I've heard multiple times before that Emmerich and Devlin do not like the direction that *SG-1* and the other series took the franchise in, as it was not the direction they intended (and searches turned up references to this but no original sources of quotes in interviews or anything of the sort.)

Apart from that, I've heard nothing about any major media endeavors, though I never followed any of the novels. I would expect though that MGM, if it is planning on creating more *Stargate* movies, would attempt not to dilute the brand or otherwise harm their box office revenue by creating more competing TV shows or direct-to-video movies in a separate but similar mythos.

http://deadline.com/2014/05/mgm-warner-bros-reboot-stargate-737858/
http://www.gateworld.net/news/2014/05/stargates-return-mgm-announces-new-movie-trilogy/